# Explore long-term data with Azure Application Insights and PowerBi

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-application-insights

I use continuous export to pull in my Application Insights data into Power Bi.  However, all of the data seems to be either 7-day or 30-day - how would I be able to view a chart with a longer-term timeframe (aka users over the last year)?

### Update

Here is what I see in Power Bi:
[image]

Comment: Right - i have a paid subscription so that data is there - I just don't get how to actually view it - in Power Bi the fields that appear to come from Azure are all in terms of 7 days or 30 days - so how can i view longer term data if every day the data from a previous time period is removed?

Comment: @yonisha - see new picture in question -

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot, it looks like you're not using Continuous Export for this, but instead are using the [Application Insights Content Pack for Power BI](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/application-insights-content-pack-for-power-bi/). The content pack has predefined views which us what you circled in your screenshot.

You can easily create your own viewed using the almost-ready-to-release Application Insights REST API (tracked with [this UserVoice suggestion](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/357324-application-insights/suggestions/4999529-make-data-accessible-via-apis-for-custom-processin)).

If you want to try this with the API, please send me a note at dalek@microsoft.com and I'll set you up. In the API documentation I show step-by-step how you can create charts from metric data in Power BI.

Thanks

Dale Koetke

Comment: Ahhh - that makes more sense!  I will send you a note for access to the API!